# Qt - pdftocairo pdf conversion process not working when application on auto start

Tags: c++, linux, qt, pdf, poppler

I am running my Qt (4.8, QWS server, QWidget app) application on an ARM/embedded linux platform. On my application, I have a module/widget to view PDF files.

Being a slower processor, it was better to go for a conversion of the PDF file to image files using `pdftocairo`. The module also has a feature to import any pdf file from a flash drive and convert it to images using `pdftocairo`. The entire module works as expected when I manually start the application from command line. Here is the code that imports the pdf file into the device in the form of images:

```
QString CacheName = PDFList->currentItem()->text(); //name of PDF file without ".pdf"
QString PDFString = "pdftocairo -jpeg -r 200 \"/media/usb/" + CacheName + ".pdf\" \"/opt/.pdf/" + CacheName + "\"";
qDebug() << PDFString;
QProcess PDFCacheprocess;
PDFCacheprocess.startDetached(PDFString); //or PDFCacheprocess.start(PDFString)
```

The ultimate goal of the project is to have the application to auto-start when the device boots up. However, when starting the application automatically, the import feature doesn't seem to do anything. I am stumped with not being able to identify the problem because I do not have any debug output (which I do have when executing the app normally).

I normally execute the application manually with

```
/opt/[path]/[application name] -qws
```

When auto-starting, I put the application out into a file, `log.txt` by adding `&>/opt/log.txt`. The output seems to be the same as when I am running with the manual command. This is the content of the file during the import process (no error being reported).

```
"pdftocairo -jpeg -r 200 "/media/usb/manual.pdf" "/opt/.pdf/manual"
```

Strangely enough, every other command (other than `pdftocairo`) is working. I tried to replace this command with `QString PDFString = "/opt/./importPDF.sh"`. The script was being executed for any command (like `reboot`), but again, it would fail if it contained the `pdftocairo` command.

I also tried to add a slot connected to `QProcess::finished(int)` to show the `QProcess` output:

```
connect(&PDFCacheprocess, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(pdfImportStatus(int)));
void UserManual::pdfImportStatus(int)
{
    qDebug()<<PDFCacheprocess.errorString()<<'\t'<<PDFCacheprocess.exitCode();
}
```

For the manual execution ( when import works), I would get:

```
"pdftocairo -jpeg -r 200 "/media/usb/manual.pdf" "/opt/.pdf/manual""
"Unknown error"      0
```

For the auto-start, `log.txt` only shows this (seems like the slot isn't being triggered?)
    `"pdftocairo -jpeg -r 200 "/media/usb/manual.pdf" "/opt/.pdf/manual""`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that the command was not being recognized in the working directory (only when auto-starting for some reason). When using a `Qprocess`, it turns out that it is always good to give the path even if the file/command exists in the environment variables - as was in my case (`$PATH`).

I had to replace the `QString` with:

```
QString PDFString = "/usr/local/bin//pdftocairo -jpeg -r 200 \"/media/usb/" + CacheName + ".pdf\" \"/opt/.pdf/" + CacheName + "\"";
```